# Angular route based on login state

Tags: angular, router

I have an Angular 5 app that allows user's to stay logged in over extended periods. We have a standard landing page for the public at large but I want regular user's to be able to go to their page right away if they are logged in. i.e. a user going to https://mysite would go to the landing page if they aren't permanently logged in and their page if they are.

To do this I have set up a dummy component that re-navigates based on the login state. Below is my code.

```
let routes = [
  { path: "", component: DefaultPageComponent },
  { path: "home", component: HomePageComponent },
  { path: "user/:id", component: MainPageComponent, data: { obj: "user" } },
  { path: "**", component: DefaultPageComponent }
];
```

and `DefaultPageComponent` is:

```
@Component({
  template: ""
})
export class DefaultPageComponent {
  constructor(router: Router, authUtils: AuthUtilsService) {
    authUtils.isLoggedIn().then(logindata => {
      if (logindata.user) {
        router.navigate(["user", logindata.user.id]);
      } else {
        router.navigate(["home"]);
      }
    });
  }
}
```

There must be a better way to do this. Anyone know?

For instance, can you set up duplicate paths with different Route Guards where one fails and the other succeeds? That will still be janky even if you could.

Comment: You need to use a route guard. The guard will check if user is logged in first, and reroute if they are logged  see https://angular.io/api/router/CanActivate

Comment: Not that simple. That user needs to be able to go to the home page (if they explicitly navigate to home for example) and other users can go to that user's personal page and see some of their info (think public vs. private profile). It's not that I want to "protect" the route I want to automate the route flow based on the entry point to the site.